# Kivy buildozer can't copy libs for armeabi-v7a

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

I have been trying to fix this issue for days and I can't seem to find any answer. I'm using the Crystax NDK with python3. I've tried using it with python2.7 and the Google NDK as well but it doesn't make a difference. It seems like buildozer just can't find the .so files it needs to copy for armeabi-v7a. Here is the log:

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.18.4 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/timothy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/timothy/Android/android-sdk-linux
# Android NDK found at /home/timothy/Android/crystax-ndk-10.3.2
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run 'python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=com.timothy.MusicBox --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3crystax,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a  --color=always --storage-dir=/home/timothy/java-neon/workspace/MusicBox/.buildozer/android/platform/build'
# Cwd /home/timothy/java-neon/workspace/MusicBox/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 21 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK
[INFO]:    Got NDK version from $ANDROIDNDKVER
[WARNING]: NDK version was set as r10.3.2, but checking the NDK dir claims it is 10.3.2.
[WARNING]: The build will try to continue, but it may fail and you should check that your setting is correct.
[WARNING]: If the NDK dir result is correct, you don't need to manually set the NDK ver.
[INFO]:    Using Crystax NDK r10.3.2
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /home/timothy/.local/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9', '5', 'clang3.6', 'clang3.7']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 5
[INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given requirements:
[INFO]:     com.timothy.MusicBox: includes recipes (hostpython3crystax, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, python3crystax, sdl2, six, pyjnius, kivy), built for archs (armeabi-v7a)
[INFO]:    com.timothy.MusicBox has compatible recipes, using this one
# Build the application #44
# Copy application source from /home/timothy/java-neon/workspace/MusicBox
# Create directory /home/timothy/java-neon/workspace/MusicBox/.buildozer/android/app
# Copy /home/timothy/java-neon/workspace/MusicBox/main.py
# Package the application
# Search and copy libs for armeabi-v7a
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('buildozer', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
File "/home/timothy/Clones/buildozer/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
File "/home/timothy/Clones/buildozer/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1010, in run_command
self.run_default()
File "/home/timothy/Clones/buildozer/buildozer/__init__.py", line 983, in run_default
self.run_command(cmd)
File "/home/timothy/Clones/buildozer/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1028, in run_command
self.target.run_commands(args)
File "/home/timothy/Clones/buildozer/buildozer/target.py", line 90, in run_commands
func(args)
File "/home/timothy/Clones/buildozer/buildozer/target.py", line 102, in cmd_debug
self.buildozer.build()
File "/home/timothy/Clones/buildozer/buildozer/__init__.py", line 210, in build
self.target.build_package()
File "/home/timothy/Clones/buildozer/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 635, in build_package
for fn in self.buildozer.file_matches(patterns):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Could you add your buildozer.spec file?